# Dictionary assignment in defined namespace failing

Tags: kdb

Firstly I show my current namespaces, then define a new one, then I try to create a dictionary.

Why does the first assignment fail, whereas assignment in a non-defined namespace is successful?

```
q)key `
`q`Q`h`o
q).foo
'.foo
q).foo:()!()
q).foo.bar:`a`b`c!1 2 3
'.foo.bar
q).foobar.bar:`a`b`c!1 2 3
q).foobar.bar
a| 1
b| 2
c| 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jgleeson. But I've read that it isn't possible to delete a context once defined? Is this the case?

Comment: I don't think you can delete a context.. Possibly a security feature to stop you from accidentally deleting .q or .Q. Interestingly @terrylynch's answer may be more correct than mine, since it initializes the context with the null element. If you look at .q or .Q etc you will see they all have this null first element. I did a few tests though and have yet to see why this element is needed.

Comment: The null element enforces a mixed list and would prevent the namespace from collapsing into a different structure in certain situations (not that its that much of a deal). For example, if you initialise it as `.foo:(`symbol$())!()` and define `.foo.bar1:`a`b`c!1 2 3` and `.foo.bar2:`a`b`c!1 2 3` then the value of the dictionary collapses into a table with type 98.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From code.kx:

> A context is actually a sorted dictionary whose domain is a **list of symbols** with the names of the entities defined in the context

If you change your code to the following, it will work as expected:

```
q).foo:(`symbol$())!()
q).foo.bar:`a`b`c!1 2 3
q).foo.bar
a| 1
b| 2
c| 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to initialize the namespace like so:

```
q).foo:enlist[`]!enlist[::]
q).foo
| ::
q)
q).foo.bar:`a`b`c!1 2 3
q)
q).foo.bar
a| 1
b| 2
c| 3
```

In the second case, q is effectively doing that for you